# PrimeNG multiSelect options not getting updated with new values

Tags: primeng

Initially multiSelect is filled with 100 values, if the search string is not listed in the initial list then server side search is implemented on enter event.

```
 <p-multiSelect 
    [options]="options"
    class="multi-select-dropdown"
    [maxSelectedLabels]="0"
    resetFilterOnHide="true"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedValues"
    (onChange)="onChange($event)"
    (keyup.enter)="onSearchFilter($event)"
    [defaultLabel]="placeholder"
    [virtualScroll]="true"
    itemSize="25"
    [style]="{'min-width':'100%', 'max-width':'100%'}">
</p-multiSelect>
```

**Issue**:
When user search for string like 'W101', if it's not available in the list then in the multiSelect "No results found" displayed".

When user hits enter, the filtered result is fetched but multiSelect is not getting updated with new values. It still shows "No results found".

But if I click the close icon(x) beside the search-box and open the drop-down then it displays the filtered list.

PrimeNG v12 is used.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue and the only solution I've fund so far has been to programatically empty the searchfield.

Answer (score 0):

A hideous workaround for me was to manually activate filter on `onFilter` event to update the multiselect component with new values.

```
@ViewChild('mySelect') mySelect: MultiSelect;

onFilter(event) {
...
this.mySelect.options = newValues;
this.mySelect.activateFilter();
...
}
```

Hope this helps anyone with the issue, but more than anything hope this can be fixed inside the framework itself.
Thanks!